# Regex to extra part of the url

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract part of a url using regex. I'm trying todo this ideally in one line and word for both url types.
I'm trying the following but not sure how I should get the second url. I am trying to extract the 4FHP from both.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> a="/url_redirect/4FHP"
>>> b="/url/4FHP/asdfasdfas/"
>>>
>>> re.search('^\/(url_redirect|url)\/(.*)', a).group(2)
'4FHP'
>>> re.search('^\/(url_redirect|url)\/(.*)', b).group(2)
'4FHP/asdfasdfas/'
```

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to match on. Are you simply looking to see if a "4FHP" exists and take it if it does? Or are you looking for "something" at a certain position inside the URL?

Comment: Lennard, as you know, SO is a question-and-answer site. Precisely what is your question?

Comment: My question is " I am trying to extract the 4FHP from both." Sorry i thought that was clear?

Comment: That isn't actually a question. That's a statement. No, it is not at all clear to me what you are asking. For more information about asking good questions, see [ask] and especially [mcve].

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks for the answer but sometimes it better not to be so ignorant. Sorry my written english language is not as good as yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `*` operator is 'greedy', so it will grab to the end of the string which is why you get `'4FHP/asdfasdfas/'` in your second example

you need to stop matching when you see another `/`, the easiest way is to use a character class that specifically excludes it, eg `[^/]`

you can also use non-capturing groups `(?: <regex> )` to only return matched group that you're interested in

```
re.search('^\/(?:url_redirect|url)\/([^/]*)', b).group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Thats very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will extract `4FHP` from either string. Noticed that I changed `.*` (match a sequence of any non-newline character) to `[^/]*` (match a sequence of any non-/ character).

```
re.search('^\/(url_redirect|url)\/([^/]*)', b).group(2)
```